# Pull out single row data without index - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Below is my data frame:

[image]

I am trying to extract row #4 header (the highlighted row) alone without their index. Below is my code:

```
df2 = pd.read_excel(readxldata, skiprows=3,header=None,sheet_name=sheetname, nrows=1)
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 7)
col_header = df2.iloc[0:7]
print(col_header)
```

The problem is, my code is pulling the row data along with index. My print output is as below:
[image]

I just want the row list data and not the index. How can that be done?

Comment: "The problem is, my code is pulling the row data along with index." This is an artifact of the representation when you `print()`. The dataframe does not directly contain these indexes. There is often a difference between the representation of data when we `print()` or otherwise display it on the screen and the actual data as it is stored in memory. It is important to keep these two concepts in mind and understand the difference.

Comment: This isn't directly related to your question, but in `pd.read_excel()` using `header=None` and `skiprows=3` means that excel row 4 is treated as data and not as column labels.  Is that what you wanted? If not perhaps you want `header=3` (4th row in excel).

Answer (score 2):

You can print it out as a string without index and header like this:

```
print(df2.to_string(index=False, header=False))
```